# Get presence from smartthings and post to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, smartthings

I have a little smarthome dashboard that I've been built in React and I want to add a presence indicator to it. Every member of my family has a presence detector device in samsung smartthings and I'd like to track the times each member of my family comes in and goes out and log it on the smarthome dashboard.

Ideally I'd like to do this using firebase as that is where the rest of my smarthome data gets stored but I can't see a way to get the data from smartthings to firebase.

To be honest, at this point I'd be happy to take the data directly from smartthings and bypass firebase alltogether but I can't work out how to do that either. The documentation seems quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a work-around solution to this using the IFTTT Maker channel.